# Simple regex is not capturing a capture group

Tags: regex

I wrote a very simple regular expression

`from.*to(.*)(?:\s|\.)`

My desire is capture the word `bos` in the string

`Posting: from jfk to bos. Need to rush`

My thinking is that this should work because I look for the word `from`, then anything up until the word `to`, then capture whatever is between `to` and either the next `.` or space.

Here is a [Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/5qR0Ku/1)

Comment: Your regex works perfectly fine, it does exactly what you asked it to.  There is a space immediately following `to`, so it returns a zero-length match.

Comment: If you want to match the next term after `to`, you can add the space before your capturing group, so it is not included, and then use a lazy quantifier to only match until the next `.` or space, rather than the last `.` or space.  This should work for your needs: `from.*to (.*?)[. ]`

Comment: @SebastianNielsen The asterisk typically defaults to greedy.  This is the case in both the PHP flavor and the Python flavor.  I don't actually know of any regex flavor that lets the asterisk default to a lazy quantifier (not saying there isn't one out there somewhere).

Comment: You simply forgot about a space after `to`. See https://regex101.com/r/5qR0Ku/4

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong I have never used PHP, so you are probably right. [This is my source](https://i.gyazo.com/e71bf9c936864038c2f42866e4734608.png) for saying PHP regex flavor defaults to lazy. How would you explain that?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen The OP specifically added the ungreedy flag (`/U`).  Notice [this](https://imgur.com/a/Z2CTelk) in the top right corner and it shows [this](https://imgur.com/a/bBS5HqT) when you click on it.  Notice if I just start a new pattern on the same site, same pattern, same regex flavor, [it behaves differently](https://regex101.com/r/MKP9ul/1).  Specifying the ungreedy flag is essentially like adding a `?` after every quantifier.

Comment: Oh right, I wasn't aware of the U flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

- greedy `.*` vs. non-greedy `.*?`, e.g. you match the second `to`
- missing space after `to`

Use this: `from.*?to (.*?)(?:\s|\.)`

Or this: `from.*?to ([^\s.]*)`

Comment: @CodyBugstein: Any questions? Does this fit your needs?